Python, trouble with os.chdir
I'm having an issue with the following Python code that aims to change the working directory using os.chdir:
if command.startswith("cd"): #C:\Users\užívateľ\Desktop\File Manager\File Manager\task\module\root_folder
  command = command[3:] #input cd task
  os.chdir(command) # command [3:] is task
  print(os.getcwd()) #os.chdir(command) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'task'

problem
The code throws a FileNotFoundError with the message "The system cannot find the file specified: 'task'".
Expected output (either):

absolute path: C:\Users\užívateľ\Desktop\File Manager\File Manager\task
relative path from current working dir: task

Can I ask where to fix the code so it changes the working directory correctly and prints the desired path (absolute or relative)?

Is the script running in the parent directory of "task"? If not you need the full path.

The issues is that python is looking for the task folder inside the current directory and the task folder is in one of the parent directories so you have to tell python to keep searching the folders and going back till it finds the right directory. os.chdir doesnt work as an absolute folder searcher. I created a function to do the searching but this only searches backwards. I hope this works
command = 'cd task'
if command.startswith("cd"):
    command = command[3:]

def find_folder(folder):
    current_directory = os.getcwd()#current folder

    # Check if task is in the folder
    if folder in os.listdir(current_directory):
        return os.chdir(folder)
    else:
        os.chdir('..')#Go back one folder
        #recall the function to do a loop
        return find_folder(folder)

find_folder(command)
print(os.getcwd())

